# MySQL Incorrect datetime value: '09:40 AM' for column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I try to enter values to the table and i got this error

`"Incorrect datetime value: '09:40 AM' for column"`

```
CREATE TABLE Class_Section (
             crn char(5) NOT NULL Primary key,
             dept_code char(3) NOT NULL,
             course_num char(3) NOT NULL,
             meeting_days varchar(6) NULL ,
             start_time datetime NULL,
             end_time varchar(8)  NULL,
             campus_code varchar(3) NOT NULL,
             location varchar(6) NOT NULL,
             faculty_id char(4) NOT NULL,
             enrollment TINYINT NOT NULL,
             capacity TINYINT NOT NULL,
             );



INSERT INTO Class_Section (
       CRN, dept_code, course_num, meeting_days, start_time, end_time, campus_code, location, faculty_id, enrollment, capacity 
       ) 
VALUES ('20761', 'PSY', '101', 'MW', '09:40 AM', '11:10 AM', 'WC','E-527', 'F002', 40, 40
       );
```

Thank you

Comment: Well, `09:40 AM` is not a `datetime`. Isn't it obvious for you?

Comment: You have `time` but not `datetime` as input.

Answer (score 1):

Use Time Datatype

And You have used **Comma** at the end of column while creating table

```
CREATE TABLE Class_Section
(
 crn        char(5) NOT NULL Primary key,
 dept_code  char(3) NOT NULL,
 course_num char(3) NOT NULL,
 meeting_days   varchar(6) NULL ,
 start_time     Time NULL,
 end_time   Time NULL,
 campus_code    varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 location   varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 faculty_id char(4) NOT NULL,
 enrollment TINYINT NOT NULL,
 capacity   TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Class_Section ( CRN, dept_code, course_num, meeting_days, start_time, end_time, campus_code, location, faculty_id, enrollment, capacity ) values ('20761', 'PSY', '101', 'MW', '09:40:00', '11:10:00', 'WC','E-527', 'F002', 40, 40);
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0e41)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e869/1) for your question.

The start_time has a DateTime type which has a format of ['YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

specify the datetime field in this format

```
    '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

> assignment said `start_time` as `datetime`.

Unless you pass a *date* value, but the *time*, as part of a *datetime* field input, the engine won't understand *just* the time as a date and time. If you have pre-decided date and time on a course start date and end date, then input them in MySQL understandable formats.

If you have date and time values separately, you can combine them to form a *datetime* value.
Following are some examples:

***Example 1***:
If you have date and time as separate values:

```
insert into tbl( col_of_type_datetime ) values( curdate(), '09:40 AM' );
insert into tbl( col_of_type_datetime ) values( '2014-02-18', '09:40 AM' );
```

***Example 2***:
If you have a known timestamp value:

```
insert into tbl( col_of_type_datetime ) values( now() );
insert into tbl( col_of_type_datetime ) values( '2014-02-18 15:10:34' );
```

***Example 3***:
If you have only date but now time value:

```
insert into tbl( col_of_type_datetime ) values( cast( curdate() as datetime ) );
insert into tbl( col_of_type_datetime ) values( curdate() );
insert into tbl( col_of_type_datetime ) values( cast('2014-02-18' as datetime) );
insert into tbl( col_of_type_datetime ) values( '2014-02-18' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have declared

```
start_time datetime ,

end_time varchar(8)
```

but while inserting, you are sending `'09:40 AM', '11:10 AM'` . So please check your datatypes once.

Comment: the assignment said start_time is datetime.
end_time – Allow a maximum of 8 characters

Comment: @user3003395 : Then you must clearly mention that in your post earlier. Don't think it has anything to 'Down vote'.

Answer (score -3):

Because you declare start_time  as datetime NULL, and mysql expects a datetime value.
Use the same type as end_time ( varchar(8)  NULL)

Comment: assignment  said start_time as datetime